# How to disable GitHub popup in Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-for-windows, github-flavored-markdown

When working in the Visual Studio Code editor, a GitHub window opens automatically

[image]

Even if I enter my GitHub credentials, this window continues to appear before this one I did not have, it really annoys me

Answer (score 0):

Try first to open a CMD and type:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
```

Close and reopen Visual Studio Code, enter your credential.

Then close and open again VSCode, to see if the issue persists.

If it does, still in a CMD (*not* `git bash`):

```sh
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core"
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|git-credential-manager-core erase
```

Repeat the erase command until you see a popup asking for your credential.
Do not enter them (click cancel)

Try and open VSCode again: enter your credentials then.
Close, and reopen to see if the issue persists.